# Scheduled notebook stopped running in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I am experiencing an issue with my scheduled notebook (managed notebooks). The scheduled notebook was set up to run on a specific schedule, but it has stopped running according to the schedule. It has ran for over a month now. And any new scheduled notebooks that i set uo do not run also. I have not made any changes to the configuration since then.

I have checked that the quotas for my project are fine.

I have reviewed the logs, but I have not found any errors or warnings related to the notebook scheduling. I also confirmed that the user account I am using to manage the notebook instance has the appropriate IAM permissions to access and manage the notebook.

Can anyone let me know what else might be the issue?

I do not have the option to reach out to the GCP support team.

Comment: Hi @dimitris_ps did the answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduled Notebooks include 2 main components:

1. Schedule
2. Execution

The schedule consists of Cloud Scheduler in a Tenant Project. This is managed by Google. When this schedule gets executed it performs a callback to Notebooks API to create an Execution.

Example: At 12:00am PST Cloud Scheduler in Tenant Project issues a API call to launch the Execution.

The execution consist of a Vertex Training job created by Notebooks API.
I would suggest to look at the following:

1. Can you create a new Execution?
2. The scheduled Execution is listed in Vertex Workbench UI?
3. Do you see any Training jobs created when the execution is supposed to be triggered.

No changes have been made to this infrastructure.
Most of the times I see this fails when user changes Vertex Training account parameters or GCS bucket permissions.